# Hide div if another div is empty from database

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I want to hide a div that it's receiving information from the database, so sometimes it has information and sometimes t doesn't, I want it to disappear if that div doesn't contain information.

Heres the code:

```js
if ($('#messageBronzeEx').html().length === 0) {
  $('#exclusionDrinksBronze').remove()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i id="exclusionDrinksBronze" class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>

<div id="page-mask"></div>
<div id="just-claimed-popup-bronze" class="popup-bronze">
  <h4><b>Exclusions for B</b></h4>
  <div id="closeExclusionBronze"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> </div>
  <div id="messageBronzeEx"></div>
</div>
```

but it just deletes the div because its basically empty (info coming from Ajax call)

I want to hide '#exclusionDrinksBronze' if '#messageBronzeEx' is empty from the database.('#exclusionDrinksBronze' is a button, and '#messageBronzeEx' is information in a popup)

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. First you say _"I want to hide a div"_, but then you go on to say _"I want to hide '#exclusionDrinksBronze'"_, but `#exclusionDrinksBronze` isn't a div, it's `<i id="exclusionDrinksBronze" class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>`

Comment: yes that's the one I want to hide, it would work the same if its a div or a button isn't it? It's just I'm using an icon as he button. The idea is just like I want to remove an element.

Comment: If you're receiving information from the database you can just check if the information is blank before putting it into the div. You shouldn't be checking `$('#messageBronzeEx').html()` you should be checking the response data from your Ajax call. If that data is blank just run `$('#exclusionDrinksBronze').hide()`

Comment: Thank you so much @cb64 !! I guess my mind is tired I didn't thought of that; I set the button as hidden and then if information was there then show it and it worked!! :)